# exceptions in rally connector

Tags: ruby, jira, rally

please help, I not understand what the problem and why connector can't stand up. There is I receive in log file (link to download log) :

http://www.ex.ua/353030445259

Please help, maybe someone receive the same error, because I have no idea what I do wrong.

Comment: Post your `jira-rest_config.xml` here.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I attach my config file in the same link.